# MarkLogic facets on binary content

Tags: properties, binary, metadata, facet, marklogic

I ingested large binary into MarkLogic using the content ingestion framework, leaving the binary files on the file system, and I used the transformation to extract metadata from the images into properties.  When I search on this content using the search API it does not return facets.  I believe that this happens because the fragment returned contains the pointer to the image on the file system and not the properties document.  Is there any way around this?  I'd like to created faceted navigation base upon the properties.

Comment: Can you elaborate which search options you pass into the search:search function? You need to declare the facets in there first. These facets need to be backed by indexes too.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the Search Developer's Guide for 5.0, section 2.2.6 talks about the fragment scope option that is new in 5.0, I think that will handle your case.  There's an example in there showing how to create a facet on the last-modified property using a local fragment scope, and it sounds like that pattern might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the search API doesn't handle this use-case, you could always call `cts:element-values` and `cts:frequency` yourself. You can still use `search:parse` and `search:resolve` to provide query parsing and basic search results.

http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#search.xqy?start=1&cat=all&query=cts%3Aelement-values&button=search